# Orient the space $B$ such that the map $f: A\to B$ is orientation preserving.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

**Setup**:  Suppose that $f: S\to \tilde S$ is a smooth map, where $S, \tilde S$ are oriented $n$- surfaces in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with smooth unit normals $N_1$ and $N_2$. Suppose that $Df_p$ is non singular for every $p\in S$.  The derivative $f$ is said to be an orientation preserving map if for all $p \in S$ and for all positively oriented bases vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ of the tangent space $S_p$ (i.e., with the property that $\det\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\\ \vdots\\ v_n\\ N_1(p)\end{pmatrix}>0$), we have $\det\begin{pmatrix}Df_p(v_1)\\ Df_p(v_2)\\ \vdots\\ Df(v_n)\\ N_2(f(p))\end{pmatrix}>0$.

If this property is satisfied for some basis $\scr B$ of $S_p$, then let's say '$f$ preserves orientation of $\scr B$.'

**Conjecture**: If for all $p\in S$, there exists a basis in $S_p$ whose orientation is preserved by $f$, then $f$ is orientation preserving.

Is this conjecture true? If yes, then I answer the following:

"Given $A= \mathbb S^1\times (-1,1), B=S^2-\{(0,0,1), (0,0,-1)\}$, and $f:A\to B, f(x,y,z)=(x\sqrt{1-z^2}, y\sqrt{1-z^2},z)$. $B$ is to be oriented such that $f$ is orientation preserving."

Take $N_1(x,y,z)= (x,y,0)$ and clearly $\det\begin{pmatrix}-y&x&0\\0&0&1\\ x&y&0\end{pmatrix}>0$, where $v_1:=(-y,x,0)^t$ and $v_2:=(0,0,1)^t$ are basis vectors of $A_p$ for $p=(x,y,z)\in A$. Calculations give: $Df(v_1)=(-y(), x(),0), Df(v_2)=(-2xz/(), -2yz/(), 1)$, where $():= \sqrt{1-z^2}$ for brevity. For trial, let's take $N_2(x',y',z')= (x',y',0), (x',y',z')\in B$.

$\det\begin{pmatrix}Df(v_1)\\ Df(v_2)\\ N_2(f(x,y,z))\end{pmatrix}=(x^2+y^2)(1-z^2)=1-z^2>0$. So with this smooth norm $N_2$ on $B$, for every $p=(x,y,z)\in A$,there exists a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of $S_p$  whose orientation is preserved by $f$. By the above conjecture, we are done.

Note that choice of $v_1, v_2$ here makes the calculations easy. Could the above can be answered in general, i.e., for **all** positively oriented basis of $S_p$ without using the conjecture? Is the conjecture even true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your conjecture is true. Here is my proof.

Let $(w_1, \dots, w_n)$ be another positively oriented basis of $S_p$, then there exists a matrix $A_{n\times n}$ such that
$$
(w_1,\dots,w_n)=(v_1,\dots,v_n)\cdot A, 
$$
that is,
$$
w_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} v_i, \quad j=1..n.
$$
(I am used to writing the basis as a row vector, since each basis element is often a column vector.)

Then we have
$$
(w_1,\dots,w_n, N_1(p))=(v_1,\dots,v_n,N_1(p))\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
A & \\
 & 1
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
By that both bases are positively oriented, taking determinants gives
$$
\det A>0.
$$

Now by linearity, we see that
$$
(Df_p(w_1),\dots, Df_p(w_n), N_2(f(p))) = (Df_p(v_1),\dots, Df_p(v_n), N_2(f(p))) \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
A & \\
 & 1
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Taking determinants, and since $f$ preserves orientation of $(v_1,\dots, v_n)$, we see
$$
\det(Df_p(w_1),\dots, Df_p(w_n), N_2(f(p)))>0,
$$
and so $f$ preserves orientation of $(w_1,\dots,w_n)$. We are done.